Configure AirspeedVelocity for Python package with PyO3 and Maturin
I'm trying  to setup Airspeed Velocity to use with my Python project. In other setups, such as github workflows the only build commands needed are:
    "python -m pip install --upgrade pip",
    "pip install .[dev] -v"

But this won't work with ASV. I have rust-PyO3 extensions and build using maturin (configured in pyproject.toml). I receive the traceback:
· Creating environments
· Discovering benchmarks
·· Uninstalling from virtualenv-py3.13
·· Building c03e16a1 <main> for virtualenv-py3.13...........
·· Installing c03e16a1 <main> into virtualenv-py3.13
·· Failed to build the project and import the benchmark suite.

This is having included the following in the asv.conf.json:
    // To build the package using pyproject.toml (PEP518), uncomment the following lines
    "build_command": [
        "python -m pip install --upgrade pip",
        "pip install .[dev] -v"
    ],

